# Adding the total for a form Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this form and can't get past the CalculateTotal. I am completely lost on how to get this to add up and display in the box. Can anyone help?

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/clbacon70/x6kjqbop/1/

```js
var gc_fSandwichPrice = 5.99; // Price for each sandwich 
var gc_fExtrasPrice = 1.50;  // Price for each extra item

// GLOBAL VARS

// Global object vars
var divErrors;
var radSandwich;
var radSize;
var chkExtras;

// Other global vars
var g_fTotal;
var g_sSandwich;
var g_sSize;
var g_sExtras;


window.addEventListener('load', Init);

function Init() {

    document.getElementById("h1Title").innerHTML = "Dirty Deli 1.0";


    var spanExtrasPrice = document.getElementById("spanExtrasPrice");
    var btnCalculateTotal = document.getElementById("btnCalculateTotal");
    divErrors = document.getElementById("divErrors");
    radSandwich = document.getElementsByName('radSandwich');
    radSize = document.getElementsByName('radSize');
    chkExtras = document.getElementsByName('chkExtras');

    spanExtrasPrice.innerHTML = gc_fExtrasPrice.toFixed(2);
    
    btnCalculateTotal.addEventListener('click', CalculateTotal);

} // function Init()



function CalculateTotal() {
        
            divErrors.innerHTML = '';
        
        if (radSandwich[0].checked) {
            g_sSandwich = radSandwich[0].value;
        } else if (radSandwich[1].checked) {
            g_sSandwich = radSandwich[1].value;
        } else if (radSandwich[2].checked) {
            g_sSandwich = radSandwich[2].value;
        } else if (radSandwich[3].checked) {
            g_sSandwich = radSandwich[3].value;
        } else {
            divErrors.innerHTML = "Select a Sandwich";
            return;
        }
        
     if (radSize[0].checked){
            g_fTotal = radSize[0].title;
        } else if (radSize[1].checked) {
            g_fTotal = radSize[1].title;
        } else if (radSize[2].checked) {
            g_fTotal = radSize[2].title;
        } else {
            divErrors.innerHTML = "Please choose a size";
            return;
        }

 
        if (chkExtras[0].checked) {
            g_sExtras = chkExtras[0].value;
            g_fTotal = g_fTotal + gc_fExtrasPrice;
        }
        if (chkExtras[1].checked) {
            g_sExtras = g_sExtras + ',' + chkExtras[1].value;
            g_fTotal = g_fTotal + gc_fExtrasPrice;      }
        if (chkExtras[2].checked) {
            g_sExtras = g_sExtras +', ' + chkExtras[2].value;
            g_fTotal = g_fTotal + gc_fExtrasPrice;
        }
 
 var textTotal = document.getElementById('textTotal');
 textTotal.value = g_fTotal;

        

 } // function CalculateTotal

function ProcessOrder() {

} // function ProcessOrder
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 background-color: #333;
}

#divWrapper {
 background-color: #efe;
 width: 40em;
 border: solid black;
 border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
 border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2em 1em;
}

h2 {
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: #666;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

input {
 margin-right: 0.3em;
}

h3, p {
 margin: 0.5em 0;
}

div#divErrors {
 font-size: 110%;
 color: white;
 background: #f00;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#divPaymentInfo {
 margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border: solid black;
 border-width: 1px 0;
}

#divCreditCardInfo {
 font-size: .8em;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin-left: 1em;
 display: inline;
}

#divOrder {
 background: white;
 min-height: 10em;
 width: 25em;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 0.5em 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="divWrapper">

 <form name="frmMain">

 <h1 id="h1Title">Deli Form</h1>
 <h2>Part 1</h2>

 <h3>Sandwich</h3>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSandwich" value="Breast of Chicken">Breast of Chicken</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSandwich" value="Leg of Lamb">Leg of Lamb</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSandwich" value="Loin of Ham">Loin of Ham</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSandwich" value="ReelMeat&reg;">ReelMeat&reg;</label><br>
 <br>

 <h3>Size</h3>
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSize" value="Manly Man"  title="$4.99">Manly Man</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSize" value="Girly Man" title="$5.99">Girly Man</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <label><input type="radio" name="radSize" value="Super Girly Man" title="$6.99">Super Girly Man</label>
 <br><br>

 <h3>Extras ($<span id="spanExtrasPrice"></span> each)</h3>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkExtras" value="Deep-Fried Spam">Deep-Fried Spam</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkExtras" value="Toenails">Toenails</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkExtras" value="Secret Sauce">Secret Sauce</label><br>
 <br><br>

 Total: <input type="text" id="txtTotal" size="5"> <input type="button" id="btnCalculateTotal" value="Calculate Total">
 <br><br>

 <div id="divErrors"></div>


 <div id="divPaymentInfo">
  <h2>Part 2</h2>

  <strong>Customer's Name:</strong> <input type="text" id="txtName">
  <br><br>

  <strong>Payment:</strong>
  <select id="selPayment">
   <option value="Cash" selected="selected">Cash</option>
   <option value="Check">Check</option>
   <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
  </select>

  <div id="divCreditCardInfo">
   Card Number: <input type="text" id="txtCreditCardNbr" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;

   Month: <input type="text" id="txtMonth" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Year:
   <select id="selYear">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2010">2017</option>
    <option value="2011">2018</option>
   </select>

  </div><!-- divCreditCardInfo -->

 </div><!-- divPaymentInfo -->


 <input type="button" id="btnProcessOrder" value="Process Order">

 <div id="divOrder"></div>

 <input type="reset" value="Reset">

 </form>

</div> <!-- divWrapper -->

</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to add brackets after 'Init'.

```
window.addEventListener('load', Init());
```

And also there was a typo in the end of CalculateTotal function.
Here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/x6kjqbop/3/

Comment: no, adding the parens after Init just invokes the Init function and passes the result (undefined) to addEventListener. addEventListener takes an event name and a callback (function object).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your javascript. You are attempting to fetch an html element with id `textTotal`, when the field you're interesting in is actually given the id `txtTotal`.

Fix that typo and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textTotal = document.getElementById('textTotal');
```

Your selector is wrong. The element id of your textbox is `txtTotal`

so the following should work:

```
var textTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed copy of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dcseekcw/

What I fixed:

- You were passing in `$` along with values you were trying to add as floats. Removed them from your title values and only put it back in after the total is calculated.
- Put in parseFloat so values could be added together instead of being concatenated as strings.
- Initialised your `g_fTotal` and `chkExtras` variables.
- Put in some basic checking so that `radSize` doesn't cause problems when it's not selected.